# High Pressure Gas Scenario

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas

Imagine a concept scenario in which there is a gas initially at standard atmospheric pressure contained in a standard mild steel cylindrical container of 10cm diameter and 1cm thickness. The pressure of the gas is theoretically raised to the same pressures seen in the centre of stars (extreme pressures) in a timeframe of 1-2 milliseconds. Where the method of achieving this pressure has no effect on the vessel itself and is purely theoretical (for the problem).

My question is, would the container be able to survive up until that point, hence would it be able to achieve the extremely high pressure, even for a fraction of a microsecond. I understand after a certain amount of time maybe 5 microseconds the container will explode, vaporise, and hence be completely destroyed, but if pressure is brought up so quickly can the container survive for a small amount of time at the same pressures seen at the centre of a star, or will it just proceed to break at the point of mild steels deformation?

The times used in this question, "1-2 milliseconds" and "5 milliseconds" are random values to help understand my thinking, in reality, the problem is just considering a situation in which the pressure increases quickly up to that point.

I haven't been able to find any information on a scenario like this in regards to pressure, but in regards to temperature, it seems that the vessel would be able to withstand a quick effect of extreme temperature, which sparked the thinking for this problem.

Comment: Well, this will greatly depend on the width of your cylinder. If your cylinder is of diameter 1 µm and its width is 100 km, well it may withstand more than what you would expect.

Comment: You're essentially asking how long the shell of a hydrogen bomb can remain intact before it explodes/vaporizes when the bomb is detonated.

Comment: @ParaH2, very true. I have added changes to the question. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The survival of the cylinder will depend on the means of producing the pressure.

The pressure at the center of a star will be in the [neighborhood of $5\times 10^9$ atmospheres.](https://www.astro.utu.fi/%7Ecflynn/Stars/l3.html). To go from 1 atm. to that much in 1 millisecond will require the radius to be decreased by a factor of about $1.7\times 10^3$. Supposing you started with 1 liter in a 10 cm wide by 12.7 cm long cylinder. That means it loses (very nearly) 5 cm of radius in 0.001 second, or it it is moving inward at 50 meters per second. Not so much. But that's the average. You need to provide all of the energy to compress it, and that rises very fast as the pressure rises.

So it has to *start* with a lot higher velocity than 50 meters per second.

So you could pound like a wild thing on the outside of the cylinder. Say with explosives. (Check out the impolosion type nuclear weapon.) And the cylinder would be destroyed *before* you achieved the pressure. Or you could have some kind of explosive inside the cylinder, which would probably rebound and destroy the cylinder about the same time as the pressure was reached.

So you would need to specify the means of achieving the pressure.

Comment: Hi @BillOnne, the pressure is theoretically raised in this situation to the desired pressure hence it is not considering how the pressure is raised, the question is more to understand what will happen from inside out. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question to make this more clear.